# Two physical web servers on port 80 behind a router

Tags: apache-2.2, routing, subdomain

#### Current scenario

I have an Apache server running on default port 80 on a CentOS 6.7 box.  I forward port 80 from my router to this machine, and I can access it from the outside with my domain `a.com`.  Everything works as expected.

#### What I want to do

I stood up a second machine, CentOS 7, to act as a dedicated [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) server.  By default, it runs the web interface through nginx on port 80.
I want to be able to access it through my subdomain `gitlab.a.com`.

---

Is this possible to do?  And if so, am I on the right track thinking it can be done with some combination of using a virtual host and a reverse proxy in Apache?  I'd prefer both of them to run on 80 if possible and not use alternate ports.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is exactly what you can do.

1. You make an A record for `gitlab.a.com` pointing to the same IP address as `a.com` in your DNS.
2. You make a virtual host for `gitlab.a.com` in your `a.com` Apache server, which contains the reverse proxy directives sending all traffic for this domain to your CentOS 7 box.